# I want to use ArrayBuffer in Dart, but got exception

Tags: dart, arraybuffer

there seems to be no ArrayBuffer defined in Dart, although people say there is.

this is my code:

```
if (event.data is ArrayBuffer)
```

this is what I got:

```
 Error: line 43 pos 23: type 'ArrayBuffer' is not loaded
```

Answer (score 3):

ArrayBuffer doesn't exist anymore. If you get a binary WebSocket frame it's returned as a [`ByteBuffer`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_typed_data/ByteBuffer.html) (requires that you set `binaryType` to `'arraybuffer'`). You can convert the ByteBuffer to a list of bytes using [`new Uint8List.view(buffer.data)`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_typed_data/Uint8List.html#view). Both classes requires an import of `dart:typed_data`.